# How to parse datetime with DateTime.ParseExact

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have the following string that I need to parse

```
string date = "2017-06-23T13:45:45.816"
```

What is correct format string?

I tried

```
DateTime createDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh-mm-ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: `Convert.ToDateTime` method will do the job

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh-mm-ss` is not `2017-06-23T13:45:45.816` you have missing milliseconds, 12 hour clock and also wrong separators.

You'd probably need something like:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fff"
```

Remember it's *ParseExact*.

Answer (score 5):

That seems an [RFC 3339](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt) date to me, so `Convert.ToDateTime` or `DateTime.Parse` will do.

```
string date = "2017-06-23T13:45:45.816";
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly You should Replace That 'T' With Blank Space ' '

```
string date = "2017-06-23T13:45:45.816";

date = date.Replace("T"," ");    // you can use this code to replace

 DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff",                                        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

 Console.WriteLine(myDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")); 

// you can try this code might be it works for u
```

Comment: Why start string replacing if the date is just a standardized date supported by the framework?

Comment: it needs to replace otherwise it enable to parse in DateTime format